# Get middle part of string in jquery

Tags: jquery, string

I have below string in js, and i just want to get just **Approval** string from below complete string,

```
<span class="label label-sm label-warning">Approval</span>
```

Thanks,

Comment: if the above html is a string, try something like `$(str).text()`, but if it's a html element use `$(".label").text()`

Comment: There are lot's of similar questions with answer. Please take a time for research and if you can't find any related to this then post your code with what you have tried.  Assigned Id OR class and get text by $('#ID').text().

Answer (score 0):

Give the element an ID and select the text via .html(). I've added a snippet for clarification:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  var value = $('#label-approve').html();
  $('#label-output').html(value);
});
```

```css
#label-approve {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

#label-output {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="label-approve" class="label label-sm label-warning">Approval</span>
<span id="label-output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

rjcode you can try do something like this:

```
$('<span class="label label-sm label-warning">Approval</span>').text()
```